# Trying to check whether there's a user with a certain e-mail address. Getting: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This method, in the users_controller is supposed to check whether there's a user with a certain e-mail address.

```
  def submit_email
    email = user_params[:user][:email]
    password = user_params[:user][:password]

    user = User.find_by_email(email)

    if user
      # Ask for password.
    else
      # Send password to e-mail
    end
  end
```

This is how user_params is defined:

```
  def user_params
    params.permit(:user, :email, :password)
  end
```

When I run it I get the error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

With this line highlighted:

```
email = user_params[:user][:email]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your `user_params` as

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
```

Your `user_params` will automatically be scoped to `:user` so you can then just do

```
email = user_params[:email]
```

Alternatively you can access the params directly, not via `user_params`

```
email = params[:user][:email]
```

The reason for the error... 
`user_params[:user]` does not exist, so it returns `nil`
`user_params[:user][:email]` is therefore the same as doing `nil[:email]` and `nil` does not support a brackets method.

Comment: I actually tried your first suggestion first, but got a different error: param is missing or the value is empty: user

Comment: And accessing the params directly leads to the same undefined method error as the code described in my question.

Comment: Make sure you're sending data in the format:
```
{ "user": {"email": "..."...}}
```

Comment: I think you need to include your view in the question, then, as it sounds like your params are structured in a non-standard way.  You can also inspect your params... install the `pry` gem, and then  after `def submit_meail` insert a new line `binding.pry` and your development controller will then halt and allow you to inspect any variables including `params`